# Adding or Modifying User in Bash Shell Script

Tags: linux

As I am trying to learn bash shell, I want to have some idea how can I add or modify the user in Bash Shell script?

Comment: What do you mean "add or modify the user"?  Which user, and for what purpose?  This does not sound like a normal request for a beginner in bash.

Comment: also this depends on your distro. But you can check *man adduser* or *man useradd*.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Ex:

Adding an user:

createuser.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

user=$1 #first argument 
apache="www-data"
passuser=$2 # second argument
newpasswd=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "S@LtStR!Ng")' $passuser)
createuser='/usr/sbin/useradd' # PATH to `useradd` package

##create and update password, then assign the apache group to the user
$createuser -d /home/$user -g $apache -m -s /bin/bash -p $newpasswd $user
```

Calling:

```
root@ip-ad-2as2-ds:#./createuser.sh test test1234
```

This way you can control the modify-user script, just change the `createuser` variable to have the proper modify-user (`usermod`) package.

Answer (score 0):

Use [adduser(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser).